# How to select objects with same features in Inkscape but only in a certain region?

Tags: inkscape, selections

I have imported a PDF. It contains approx. 30000 objects which make it sluggish to render. Some objects like texts are expendable in most parts of the drawing but not in a part of the center.

So I want to remove a lot of details in at least 2/3 of the drawing to simplify it. I'm able to select (and remove) e.g. all Texts written in white by selecting one and applying "select similar by contour and filling". Now I want to do this only in the areas I want to simplify.

So my approach was to group all objects of one area, where I wanted to simplify objects, enter the group and do the "select similar things", but this selects everything similar outside the group along with those I want to delete.

I also tried to select all and do a "group deselect" by pressing shift and dragging a rectangle, but this did not work (as it was apparently not intended to work that way).

Are there other means of removing small related features (text, small circles, lines of certain colour) in the periphery of the drawing?

Converting something into bitmap is only my last resort due to the details needed vs. horrible file size.

Comment: Not having your file makes it hard to imagine. Try "masking" by first selecting your "for keeps" region and locking all those elements. Then do your feature-select again and see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the image contains business secrets (construction data), which makes it difficult to share. It's basically a lot of straight lines, circles, texts and boxes with no special features like shading or splines. But I'm going to test, what you suggested.